# Prepending custom dirs ($ZPFX/{include,libs}) to CPP..../LDFLAGS with use of config.site file of autotools?

Tags: configure, autotools, autoconf, compiler-flags, cflags

I'm using a `$CONFIG_SITE` set to `$ZPFX/share/config.site` file containing:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I$ZPFX/include $CPPFLAGS"
LDFLAGS="-L$ZPFX/lib $LDFLAGS"
```

where `$ZPFX` variable is my custom user prefix, similar to `~/.local`.

Now, the problem is that the system `iconv.h` (under path `/usr/include`) isn't found because of this, as only the above pre-set (with use of `config.site`) `-I$ZPFX…/-L$ZPFX…` are being passed to the test program, as the following lines from `config.log` are showing:

```
configure:21831: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 \
   -I/home/q/.local/share/zinit/polaris/include  \
   -L/home/q/.local/share/zinit/polaris/lib  \
   conftest.c  -lxml2     -liconv >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -liconv
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(`$ZPFX` is expanded to its value, which is: `/home/q/.local/share/zinit/polaris`)

*The Question*: how to append (prepend) any custom (`$ZPFX/…` in my case) directories to  `CPPFLAGS/LDFLAGS`, preserving their default values? So that my custom libraries are only given *higher precedence*, and **not** *exclusivity*?

*What I've tried*

As it can be seen, I've tried to prepend to the flags by appending any occurred values at the time of sourcing the `config.site` file, by `"…$CPP…/$LDFLAGS"` :

```
CPPFLAGS="-I$ZPFX/include $CPPFLAGS"
LDFLAGS="-L$ZPFX/lib $LDFLAGS"
```

However this has no effect.

I'm also waving between not-appending and appending any typically used system-libraries paths: `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib{,64}`, however I don't like the idea, because some system might use e.g.: `/opt/…` for main prefix, making such hack not working at all.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.71/html_node/Site-Defaults.html#Site-Defaults) explains how `configure` scripts use `CONFIG_SITE`.  The parts most relevant to your question are near the beginning:

> If the environment variable `CONFIG_SITE` is set, `configure` uses its
> value as a space-separated list of shell scripts to read [...].
> Otherwise, it reads the shell script `prefix/share/config.site` if it
> exists, then `prefix/etc/config.site` if it exists. [...]
>
> Site files can be arbitrary shell scripts

You ask:

> how to append (prepend) any custom (`$ZPFX/…` in my case) directories
> to `CPPFLAGS/LDFLAGS`, preserving their default values? So that my
> custom libraries are only given *higher precedence*, and not
> *exclusivity*?

You need to read only a little between the lines to recognize that the mechanism by which `configure` scripts read site defaults must be via the `.` command.  That the files may contain arbitrary shell code and that they can set shell variables within `configure` implies that they are going to be parsed and executed as shell code.

The docs also say what `configure` does by default when you do not provide `CONFIG_SITE`, so your site config can do that, too, if you wish.  And that's what I *would* do, to start.  Specifically, add this at the beginning of `$ZPFX/share/config.site`:

```
test -r "${prefix}/share/config.site" && . "${prefix}/share/config.site"
test -r "${prefix}/etc/config.site" && . "${prefix}/etc/config.site"
```

Now you have the same settings that `configure` would get when you don't define `CONFIG_SITE` at all.  What remains is to insert your own additional settings, and the code already presented in the question ought to be fine for that:

> ```
> CPPFLAGS="-I$ZPFX/include $CPPFLAGS"
> LDFLAGS="-L$ZPFX/lib $LDFLAGS"
> ```

---

Additionally, you write:

> I'm also waving between not-appending and appending any typically used
> system-libraries paths: `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib{,64}`, however I
> don't like the idea, because some system might use e.g.: `/opt/…` for
> main prefix, making such hack not working at all.

I don't like that idea either.

In the first place, `/usr/include`, `/usr/lib`, *etc*. are not just *commonly used*, they are typical toolchain defaults.  You pretty much never need to explicitly specify toolchain defaults, and trying to do so is more likely to cause harm than good.  For example, it could cause breakage in cases such as you posit, where the defaults for the toolchain actually being used are different from the usual ones.

But in the second place, your remarks convey an incorrect perspective on what you're doing with site defaults.  These are *site-specific*, which may mean machine specific or may mean more broadly specific to a group or organization, but any way around, you can set only your own site defaults, not those of other sites.

And that leads me to one final point: the site configuration is part of your *site*, not part of your *project*.  Hopefully this is not a point of confusion for you, but I want to be sure it is clear.  You should not be planning to distribute your site configuration file outside your own site, nor to rely on people wanting to build your project at other sites specifically to use a site configuration file to inject build settings.